# View as parameter, but view initializer is nil

Tags: iphone, uiview, view

I'm trying to use the MBProgressHUD found here but i have a problem.

I want to able to show the UIView progress indicator when a new UIViewController is loaded

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view.window];
}
```

The problem is that the view is not yet initialize and returns an exception.

How can i overcome this?

Teo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude you never want to write code like this:

```
self.view.window //In iOS projects, *window* is such a holy thing that only the *AppDelegate is responsible to handle
```

In MBProgressHUD's official sample code, they code this way:

```
mbProgressHUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
```

Comment: Honestly i don't. Thanks for that. Maybe a off topic, but if my UIViewController has a tableview and the ProgressHUD appears, until it finishes it will scroll up and down with the tableview. Can this be done with MBProgressHUD or does is another approach required?

Comment: I've no experience in making tableViews scroll up and down by themselves. But if you just want to use this effect to tell the user that *data is not ready, please wait*, I suggest you use the MBProgressHUD's animation effect instead. It's much more natural and easier to recognize and understand.

Comment: Yes, i mean if the user intentionally pans the blank tableview it will scroll up and down a little bit. Not that much harm done, but i've seen it in other applications been fixed to position.